# Slice numpy array to make it desired shaped

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Surprisingly, couldn't find the answer across the internet. I have an n-dimensional numpy array. E.g.: 2-D np array:

```
array([['34.5500000', '36.9000000', '37.3200000', '37.6700000'],
       ['41.7900000', '44.8000000', '48.2600000', '46.1800000'],
       ['36.1200000', '37.1500000', '39.3100000', '38.1000000'],
       ['82.1000000', '82.0900000', '76.0200000', '77.7000000'],
       ['48.0100000', '51.2500000', '51.1700000', '52.5000000', '55.2500000'],
       ['39.7500000', '39.5000000', '36.8100000', '37.2500000']], dtype=object)
```

As you can see, the 5th row consists of 5 elemnts and **i want to make the 5th dissapear**, using something like this:

```
np.slice(MyArray, [6,4])
```

[6,4] is a shape. I really DO not want to iterate threw dimensions and cut them. I tried the `resize` method, but it returns nothing!

Comment: Actually, your array is just a vector of lists.

Comment: @wim But all np n-dimensional arrays are vector of vector of ...n-1 times.... of lists, arent they?

Comment: What's the shape of this array?  `MyArray.shape`?

Comment: `np.array` are not implemented as lists of lists.  The display looks like it, but internally that's not how `numpy` works.  But in this case you do have an array of lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a 2d array.  It is a 1d array, whose elements are objects, in this case some 4 element lists and one 5 element one.  And this lists contain strings.

```
In [577]: np.array([['34.5500000', '36.9000000', '37.3200000', '37.6700000'],
     ...:        ['41.7900000', '44.8000000', '48.2600000', '46.1800000'],
     ...:        ['36.1200000', '37.1500000', '39.3100000', '38.1000000'],
     ...:        ['82.1000000', '82.0900000', '76.0200000', '77.7000000'],
     ...:        ['48.0100000', '51.2500000', '51.1700000', '52.5000000', '55.25
     ...: 00000'],
     ...:        ['39.7500000', '39.5000000', '36.8100000', '37.2500000']], dtyp
     ...: e=object)
Out[577]: 
array([['34.5500000', '36.9000000', '37.3200000', '37.6700000'],
       ['41.7900000', '44.8000000', '48.2600000', '46.1800000'],
       ['36.1200000', '37.1500000', '39.3100000', '38.1000000'],
       ['82.1000000', '82.0900000', '76.0200000', '77.7000000'],
       ['48.0100000', '51.2500000', '51.1700000', '52.5000000', '55.2500000'],
       ['39.7500000', '39.5000000', '36.8100000', '37.2500000']], dtype=object)
In [578]: MyArray=_
In [579]: MyArray.shape
Out[579]: (6,)
In [580]: MyArray[0]
Out[580]: ['34.5500000', '36.9000000', '37.3200000', '37.6700000']
In [581]: MyArray[5]
Out[581]: ['39.7500000', '39.5000000', '36.8100000', '37.2500000']
In [582]: MyArray[4]
Out[582]: ['48.0100000', '51.2500000', '51.1700000', '52.5000000', '55.2500000']
In [583]:
```

To `slice` this you need to iterate on the elements of the array

```
In [584]: [d[:4] for d in MyArray]
Out[584]: 
[['34.5500000', '36.9000000', '37.3200000', '37.6700000'],
 ['41.7900000', '44.8000000', '48.2600000', '46.1800000'],
 ['36.1200000', '37.1500000', '39.3100000', '38.1000000'],
 ['82.1000000', '82.0900000', '76.0200000', '77.7000000'],
 ['48.0100000', '51.2500000', '51.1700000', '52.5000000'],
 ['39.7500000', '39.5000000', '36.8100000', '37.2500000']]
```

Now with all the sublists the same length, `np.array` will create a 2d array:

```
In [585]: np.array(_)
Out[585]: 
array([['34.5500000', '36.9000000', '37.3200000', '37.6700000'],
       ['41.7900000', '44.8000000', '48.2600000', '46.1800000'],
       ['36.1200000', '37.1500000', '39.3100000', '38.1000000'],
       ['82.1000000', '82.0900000', '76.0200000', '77.7000000'],
       ['48.0100000', '51.2500000', '51.1700000', '52.5000000'],
       ['39.7500000', '39.5000000', '36.8100000', '37.2500000']], 
      dtype='<U10')
```

Still strings, though

```
In [586]: np.array(__,dtype=float)
Out[586]: 
array([[ 34.55,  36.9 ,  37.32,  37.67],
       [ 41.79,  44.8 ,  48.26,  46.18],
       [ 36.12,  37.15,  39.31,  38.1 ],
       [ 82.1 ,  82.09,  76.02,  77.7 ],
       [ 48.01,  51.25,  51.17,  52.5 ],
       [ 39.75,  39.5 ,  36.81,  37.25]])
```

Comment: That's not raelly what i seeked to see, but thats nice, thanks.
Are the last ouput's elements are string? Does this fact restricts me in the numpy functionality usage?

Comment: The last expression produces a 2d array of floats.

Comment: sorry, my bad, was confused with your comment before)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an almost* vectorized approach -

```
def slice_2Dobject_arr(arr,out_shape):
    lens = np.array(map(len,arr))
    id_arr = np.ones(lens.sum(),dtype=int)
    id_arr[lens[:-1].cumsum()] = -lens[:-1]+1
    mask = id_arr.cumsum()<=out_shape[1]
    vals = np.concatenate(arr)
    return vals[mask].reshape(-1,out_shape[1])[:out_shape[0]]
```

*: Almost because of the use of `map` at the start to get the lengths of the lists in the input array, which seems isn't a vectorized operation. But, computationally that should be comparatively negligible.

Sample runs -

```
In [92]: arr
Out[92]: array([[3, 4, 5, 3], [3, 7, 8], [4, 9, 6, 4, 2], [3, 9, 4]], dtype=object)

In [93]: slice_2Dobject_arr(arr,(4,3))
Out[93]: 
array([[3, 4, 5],
       [3, 7, 8],
       [4, 9, 6],
       [3, 9, 4]])

In [94]: slice_2Dobject_arr(arr,(3,3))
Out[94]: 
array([[3, 4, 5],
       [3, 7, 8],
       [4, 9, 6]])

In [95]: slice_2Dobject_arr(arr,(3,2))
Out[95]: 
array([[3, 4],
       [3, 7],
       [4, 9]])
```

Comment: Thats cool, i will try it right now. Are there any benifitials, cmpared to the previus answer??

Comment: @VladislavLadenkov Well it seems the other answer uses `loop comprehension`. So, the benefits might be seen on performance when you have a huge number of lists in that input array.

Comment: This solution flattens the array, and uses a mask to slice out the undesired stuff, and finally reshapes.  You'd have to do speed tests on a realistic size array if speed (v. legibility) matters.

Comment: @hpaulj True there is some setup overhead there, so as I said we would need a huge number of lists in that array to see any potential benefits.